# Ceiling drywall crack recurring problem at screw location

Tags: drywall, ceiling, screws, crack, spackling-paste

I have a drywall crack in the ceiling that keeps coming back. It is at the location of the drywall screw. Last year I applied a regular drywall patch and then painted over when it dried. But less than a year later it came back. I live in Mid Atlantic US and there is some structure expansion/contraction between summer and winter times. What should I do for the crack not to be coming back? On the picture there is crack location next to wall corner, the screw is on the ceiling side.
Thanks,
DV
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the screw was installed too deep and ripped through the paper and thus has no support. Add a screw flush with the paper 1" away into the joist. Then patch with setting compound and paper tape, finish as usual